# Rails - Trying to serialize a DB table but getting undefined method `serialize' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a table so I can save and retrieve hashes from it.

page model

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.text  :title
      t.text  :content_top
      t.text  :content_bottom
      t.text  :table_head
      t.text  :table_content
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    serialize :table_head
    serialize :table_content
  end
end
```

When I run the DB migration I get the following error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'serialize' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x007fd31c11f318>`

Not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method serialize inside ActiveRecord::Migration. `serialize` mehod should be used inside model

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end
```

Reference link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Ah woops wasn't paying attention to that. Thanks

Comment: It happens sometimes.